# Hardcode an Array in a For Loop

Tags: java

I am trying to write a Java class which needs to be as short as possible (line-wise). Within my class, I have the following code:

```
char[] myArray = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
for(char c : myArray) ...
```

In order to make this shorter, as I will always be iterating over the same chars, I thought that I might be able to do something like this:

```
for(char c : {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}) ...
```

However, this doesn't work and I cannot find anything online to show me how to do this (I'm not really sure what to search for this).

Is this possible in a different way? Or can this not be made any shorter?

Comment: why the class has to be short as possible (line wise) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the chars form a consecutive pattern, you can just use

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'd'; c++)
```

If they don't, you could use

```
for (char c : new char[] {'c', 'a', 'b'})
```

or

```
char[] arr = {'c', 'a', 'b'};   
for (char c : arr)
```

or

```
for (char c : "cab".toCharArray())
```

Comment: Of the final 3 (my chars aren't consecutive), do you know which would be most efficient?

Comment: @Haych No I don't I'm afraid - I know very little about things like that. I doubt it's the last one as that needs both a `String` and a `char[]`.

Answer (score 5):

You need the type identifier for the array aswell as

```
for(char c : new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'})  {
   ...      
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are after is `for(char c : new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}) ...` the syntax without the `new char[]` is just for convenience if used in the definition of the variable as there the type can be inferred clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
for(char c : new char[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative for the obvious solution postet in the other answers, 
Why not write all in one line if you are a code golfer.

```
char[] a={'a','b','c','d'}; for(char c:a) ...
```